# What are the commands which will work in unix but won't work in linux

Tags: linux, unix-philosophy

Pls list the command or the scenario which will work in Unix but will never work in Linux

Comment: I can't tag with unix

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Linux is the kernel found in a wide variety of Unix-like (Debian, RHEL, OpenSuse...), and not-so-Unix-like (Android, ChromeOS, smart TVs...) systems. Unix denotes a wide family of operating systems which in some acceptances of the term includes those Linux-based systems like Debian/RHEL... All different Unix and Unix-like systems (thousands of different ones) have different commands, all of them have optional commands. Which kernel they use is of limited relevance.

Comment: @Stephane I am currently using ksh88 version for script  and we are planning for rhel6.So is there any limitations in it

Comment: `ksh88` in what OS? `Unix` is not an OS nowadays, it's a family. Unix OSes include Apple OS/X, AIX, Solaris, HPUX, Tru64... If you want a shell available on RHEL that is compatible with ksh88, ksh93 is probably your best bet though pdksh/mksh may be enough. As for the commands used that obviously depends on which ones?

Comment: See the [Unix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) for a list of standard basic utilities available in most Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 2):

There are many variations of UNIX (BSD, AIX, Solaris for e.g.) and many Linux-based operating systems (RHEL, Ubuntu, SUSE for e.g.).

Although there are some [standard utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_commands) and [shell command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)s, it would be impossible to compare available commands in the OS families as a whole.

A more practical exercise would be comparing a UNIX variation with a Linux distribution. However, even then, the room for package customization may make it difficult to come up with anything definitive.